# Attach image to Yii contact form

Tags: php, forms, email, yii

Hi I've been trying to figure out how to attach an image to an email to be sent to user of the contact form. All it does right now is literally attach the filename of the image to the email but not the actual image:

Site Controller:

public function actionContact()
    {

```
    $model=new ContactForm;
    if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
    {   
        $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
        if($model->validate())
        {
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            $model->image->saveAs('/tmp/emailScap');

            $headers="From: {$model->email}\r\nReply-To: {$model->email}";
            mail(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'],$model->subject,$model->body,$model->image,$headers);
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
            $this->refresh();
        }
    }
    $this->render('contact',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Model:

class ContactForm extends CFormModel

{

```
public $name;
public $email;
public $subject;
public $body;
public $image;
public $verifyCode;

/**
 * Declares the validation rules.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        // name, email, subject and body are required
        array('name, email, subject, body', 'required', 'message'=>'{attribute} 不可以為空。'),
        // email has to be a valid email address
        array('email', 'email', 'message'=>'請填寫正確的{attribute}。'),
        // verifyCode needs to be entered correctly
        array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(), 'message'=>'認證碼不可以為空。'),
        // Image
        array('image', 'file', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'safe'=>true, 'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, gif, png'),
    );
}
```

Comment: Go through thi link http://fil.ya1.ru/PHP_5_in_Practice/index.htm#page=0768667437/ch16lev1sec1.html

Comment: keep the images in the server and just pass the link with image tag in the mail function

Comment: Hey thanks this method works! But I ended up using Mutt instead haha thanks!